# How do I get the text value of a combobox field in a table in vba

Tags: vba, ms-access, controlbox

I am writing a function that searches tables for a particular string.

The function opens a recordset.
For each record it checks the value of each field to see if it matches the string

The problem is that some of the fields are comboboxes so the value is the ID, but I'm looking for the string.
I tried using column, but it throws an error.

I have some code that goes through the properties of each field, so I can tell that the field is in fact a combobox.

There has to be a simpler way to do this...

```
Public Sub FindTableValue(WhatToFind As String)
' This procedure searches each table for the WhatToFind string.
' The function prints results in the Immediate Window.
    On Error GoTo FindTableValue_Err
   
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim tbl As DAO.TableDef
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
    
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim value As Variant
    Dim str As String
    
    Set db = CurrentDb
       
    For Each tbl In CurrentDb.TableDefs
        If Not Left(tbl.Name, 4) = "MSys" Then
            If InStr(1, tbl.Name, WhatToFind) > 0 Then
                Debug.Print tbl.Name & " name"
            End If
            Debug.Print "Searching in table: " & tbl.Name
            Debug.Print "--------------------------------"

            With rs
                Do While Not rs.EOF
                    For i = 0 To tbl.Fields.count - 1
                        str = Nz(rs.Fields(i).value, "null")
                        If (InStr(1, str, WhatToFind, vbTextCompare) > 0) Then
                            Debug.Print Tab(4); rs.Fields(i).Name; Tab(20); ": " & str
                        End If
                        'Check to see if this is a combo box.
                        ' The property is a "displaycontrol" and
                        ' the value is 111
                        For j = 0 To .Fields(i).Properties.count - 1
                            If .Fields(i).Properties.Item(j).Name = PROPERTY_NAME_DISPLAY_CONTROL Then
                                If .Fields(i).Properties.Item(j).value = PROPERTY_VALUE_COMBOBOX Then
                            
                                 ' "WHAT GOES HERE IF IT IS A COMBOBOX??

                                End If
                            End If
                        Next j
                    Next i
                    rs.MoveNext
                Loop
                Debug.Print ;
                rs.Close
            End With
        End If
    Next tbl
   
FindTableValue_Exit:
    On Error Resume Next
    rs.Close
    Debug.Print "ALL DONE!!!"
    Exit Sub

FindTableValue_Err:
    If (Err.number <> 3001) Then
        Debug.Print "Error " & Err.number & " " & Err.Description
    End If
    Resume Next
    'Resume FindTableValue_Exit
End Sub
```

Any guidance would be appreciated TIA

Comment: The field is NOT a combobox. Combobox is just property setting for field, whatever data type it may be. I advise not to build lookup fields in table. See http://access.mvps.org/Access/lookupfields.htm.  Column index is property of combobox control on form. You would have to search a query that joins tables and do search on descriptive text field from the lookup table.

Comment: Why are you doing this search? What do you want to accomplish?

Comment: If you are searching multiple fields for a string, I suspect data structure is not normalized.

Comment: One of the first lessons I learnt with Access.... _thou shalt abhor the use of "Lookup Fields" which art the creation of the Evil One._

Comment: The other commandments http://access.mvps.org/access/tencommandments.htm. No.3 should include "no special characters nor all upper case".

Comment: I am searching multiple fields for a string because I am writing a search function.  I'm sure I am missing a ridiculously easy answer, but if I don't have a lookup field, how do I look up the field?  Even if I use the first column, it's still a lookup field isn't it?  So the question remains, how do I write VBA to find out if a text field associated with an Id matches the string I am searching for?

Comment: Did some looking around. I can convert the lookup fields to their underlying key value.  I'm still wondering if the search I want to do is possible.